# Pass id to new create form (but not through URL) - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I used the following advice to set up new_invoice_path in my app:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570788

How can I (using the outlined scenario in the question/answer I linked to above) make it so that when a user clicks a link to create a new invoice for a specific account the account_id passes to the form but does not show up in the URL?

**I view the current solution (pass account_id to form via URL) as problematic because...**

1. Someone could easily modify the URL and start creating invoices in different accounts.
2. It looks sloppy (especially if you start trying to pass things other than just account_id)

Comment: Have you considered using a session variable?

Comment: @jvillian I'm new to rails so I'm not clear on if session variable can only be stored if a user is logged in. In this case, there are no users, only different accounts.

Comment: Using the session does not require that the user is logged in. You can read the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) for more information. Naturally, you'll want to manage the session thoughtfully so that you don't accidentally end up creating invoices for the wrong account.

Comment: there is no vulnerability if you use some authorization gems - https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan / https://github.com/varvet/pundit, or you can do it manually. With the help of them you check who owns the account, and if user has not this account, he sees Access Denied. About pass through url params - in linked sample hidden_field used - url does not contains it's value

Comment: @SergeySokolov that's an interesting gem (will star it for future projects) but there aren't any users. As for the hidden form field, I'm getting "?account_id=1" affixed to the end of the URL which could be modified to save to another account.